# Linux bash: No such file or directory message for existing file

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I have a strange error occurring on one of my servers - despite a file existing, I cannot run it:

[image: image of error]

This is not limited to this particular program or to the user. It also happens when I try to run the file with the full path. Execute permissions are globally given for this file.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `strace /path/to/sourceguardian`?

Comment: You know you can copy-and-paste *text*, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible reason for this error is when you try to execute a binary file which is not compatible with your platform. For example, you get such an error when you execute a 32-bit binary on 64-bit OS.

You can check your system platform using: `uname -a`. You need to know whether this program is compatible or not with your system.

Comment: Super! This was the solution...all I had to do was install the "ia32-libs" package via aptitude and now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: @Aron: I was about to edit my answer to tell you that, but I was not sure if this is really the problem or something else. Good to hear that :)

Comment: You'd be able to test this by running ```ldd /path/to/file``` and it will then complain about libraries which are required but not found.